# I want to set the Streaming replication between two different postgresql versions

Tags: postgresql

my primary server is Postgresql-9.4 and the secondary server is Postgresql-13, I followed all the steps but while restarting the secondary server, I am facing the error "An old version of the database format was found. You need to dump and reload before using PostgreSQL 13." how I should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have streaming replication between different PostgreSQL versions, and you cannot have logical replication with versions less than v10.

You will have to use trigger-based replication like with [Slony-I](https://slony.info/).

Comment: So i cant even do streaming replication where primary is postgresql-9.4 and secondary is postgresql-9.6?

Comment: Yes, because they are different major versions.